# Change font colour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering if someone can assist me with the css and html code in changing the font colour on header one and header three. I have attached a screen shot of the page. Currently it is white with a shadow however, I was just wanting it black without a shadow. At the moment, because the font is white I cannot see the words, Michelle Lindemann's Magical stories. I have attached a screen shot of the page as well as copied my current coding. I hope this helps. Thanks so much I appreciate it. 
Michelle xx

```css
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 60%;
}


.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .1rem black;

}

.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .6rem black;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.btn {
    font-weight: 500;
    border-width: medium;
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
                 <div class="carousel-item active">
                     <img src="img/meheaderwordstwo.png">
                     <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                         <h1 class="display-2"></h1>Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories</h1>
                         <h3>Bringing your dreams to life!</h3>
                         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">DISCOVER MORE</a>


                     </div>
```

[image: image of the page]

Thanks

Comment: The code attached works the way you wanted it to, black font though there's a shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `color: black;` to the `.carousel-caption h3` section.  As of right now your code should already be doing this, but I'm assuming you're asking this queston because its not.  Try adding `!important;` to the color and it might work as something else might be effecting the text color. See what I did here: (I made it blue for the example. you can change it to black).

```css
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 60%;
}


.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .1rem black;
   

}

.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .6rem black;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
     color: blue !important;
}

.btn {
    font-weight: 500;
    border-width: medium;
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
                 <div class="carousel-item active">
                     <img src="img/meheaderwordstwo.png">
                     <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                         <h1 class="display-2"></h1>Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories</h1>
                         <h3>Bringing your dreams to life!</h3>
                         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">DISCOVER MORE</a>


                     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of font, you use the `color:` option in css.

Example:

```
.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: black;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;

    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help. Michelle xx

Comment: @MichelleLindemann No problem happy to help! I see you are new here to stack overflow. When you get an answer and it works for you, you should click the checkmark next to the answer which will mark the question as answered. Then if anyone else has the same problem as you, they know where to look to get the correct solution.